# How to read effectively data (the same type) from file line after line to several vectors (vector of vectros)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a file with more than 100 pcs. of elements (the same type of data e.g ints). Every elements is in other line.
Structure of file:
int 
int 
... 
int

I have to read this data to 2D array (vector of 5 vectors):
- first line to first vector
- second line to second vector
....
- fifth line to fifth vector
- sixth line to first vector...

and from the beginning until the end of the file.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_v;
std::ifstream in( "data.txt" );
std::string record;

while ( std::getline( in, record ) )
{
    std::istringstream is( record );
    std::vector<int> row( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ),
                             std::istream_iterator<int>() );
    my_v.push_back( row );
}

for ( const auto &row : my_v )
{
    for ( double x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Now i'm reading data to one vector. How to fix it ?

Comment: I was looking but unfortunately I did not find it  the same(I'm still looking)

Comment: Not very clear what you want. When you read the sixth line and put it in the first vector, what happens to the data that is already in the first vector? In your file format you seem to be saying there in one `int` per line, but your code allows for several `int`s per line. Which is it?

Comment: first int (line) to first place in first vector, second int(line) to first place in second vector.... sixth int (line) to second place in first vector etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code seems to be for a somewhat different format. I'm guessing you didn't actually write this code yourself and don't really understand it. Based on the description and a little common sense I think what you are looking for is this

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_v(5); // five vectors
std::ifstream in("data.txt");
int value, i = 0;

// read a value
while (in >> value)
{
    // add to the 'i'th vector
    my_v[i].push_back(value);
    // update i
    if (++i == 5)
        i = 0;
}

// print results
for ( const auto &row : my_v )
{
    for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is exacly what i wanted. Thank you.